# How to move the control to next opened accordion on tab press

Tags: angular, accordion, primeng

I am building an angular 6 application which contains PrimeNG accordions as well. Each accordion contains multiple  input fields. How to move the focus/control to next opened accordion if the next one is closed.

Consider if we have 3 accordions 
 1st accordion is opened 
 2nd accordion is closed 
 3rd accordion is opened

Now control were in input field of first accordion. On tab key press control is moving to 2nd accordion's input fields instead of moving to 3rd accordion

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Can you please show us some code and example?

Comment: tip:Use ViewChildren https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren and focus in changes.subscribe to the first element of the queryList

Comment: I think you have to post some code. I created simple app with the accordion and some simple controls and when pressing the tab the focus is properly moved to the next tab.